# How to make ( #text) clickable in webview or textview?

Tags: iphone

I have a text comins as " This is very nice #thing" ,I want that text contaning  "#" would be on a different color and clicking on it should open a new View.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use UIWebView and make the clickable items standard HTML anchors then monitor the link loading in UIWebViewDelegate method ***shouldStartLoadWithRequest***

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL* u = [request URL];

    if( [[u scheme] isEqualToString:@"showlicenses"] ) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
            pathForResource:@"credits" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"help"];

        LicensesWebviewController *vc = [[LicensesWebviewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
        [vc release];

        return NO; // DO NOT attempt to load URL
    }

    return YES; // if you want to allow the URL to load
}
```

You'll need to set the delegate on your UIWebView.

myWebView.delegate = self;

So anytime a link in my HTML page with the format: "showLicenses://blahblah" is tapped, I push a new view controller.

You can use any type of links you want, you just have to examine and trap the ones you want handled internally. e.g., "myscheme:///do/something/with/this/link"

Comment: Well... that code provides an example, but 
[[LicensesWebviewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] is a ViewController in one of my apps. you have to write your own, or do whatever you want with the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UIWebView then you have html markup available to you.  So you could do something like this:

```
NSString *html = @"This is a very nice <font color=\"green\">#thing</font>";
[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost"]];
```

Comment: But as text are coming is random , than how to detect it at runtime ??

Comment: I suppose you'd do a search and replace on the text to "detect at runtime"